# iterating down panda series appending lines that start with letters to the end of lines that start with numbers

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am having some troubles getting my head around this for-loop using python.  Below is a one column dataframe as an example.  Most pandas examples that I have found are geared towards addressing the entire dataframe at one time. Or searching for a word and appending to the previous line.

```
What I am trying to do: Forgive me trying to sound it out in a logical way.
1-Start at (0,Test) in the series.
2-Check element at (0,Test) for number at first position (0). If True, then hold and (store) 
  pre_number_line.
3-Goto next line down.
4-Check element (1,Test) for number at first position (0). If False, then check first position for 
  letter.
5-If first character True for letter, concatenate current line at the end of the pre_num_line or 
  (0,Test) position line in this case.
6-Delete current row & shift rows up.(instead maybe change string(line) to NaN and delete all NaN at 
  end of code). Not sure which is easier.
7-Analyze next row down at (2,Test) repeat process starting at step 2. 
8-End loop when all rows with letters (at 1st position) have been appended to the pre_num_line.
9-Next row down, should start with numbers. This will be the new pre_num_line.
```

Listed are only the beginning of the string. Although, the string can have numbers and letters throughout. The first position of each row is always a number or letter(case insensitive). Each lettered row must be combined (at the end) with the numbered row above it. At the end of the processing only the numbered rows exist.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series


dat = {'Test': ['123456ab', 'coff-4', 'eat 8', 'bagle6', '345678-edh', 'wine', 'bread','567890 tfs', 
       'grape']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
numbers = '0123456789'


#------------------- 
pre_num_lin = None

for line in df.Test:
    if line[0] in numbers:
        pre_num_lin = df['Test']

if line[0] in letters:
    pre_num_lin = pre_num_lin + ' ' + line

#------------------

print(df)



What it should look like at end:
Test
0 123456ab coff-4 eat 8 bagle6
1 345678-edh wine 4 bread
2 567890 tfs grape
```

I thank you all for your time and knowledge. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(df['Test'].str[0].str.isnumeric().cumsum())['Test'].agg(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
Test
1    123456ab coff-4 eat 8 bagle6
2           345678-edh wine bread
3                567890 tfs grape
Name: Test, dtype: object
```

Details:

Use the string accessor and an indexer of zero to get the first letter `df['Test'].str[0]` equal to `df['Test'].str.get(0)` (just less typing)

Next, use the string accessor with `isnumeric` method to check to see if that character is a number or not. This returns a boolean series.

```
df['Test'].str[0].str.isnumeric()

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
Name: Test, dtype: bool
```

Now, we can use `cumsum` to create groupings of lines like this:

```
df['Test'].str[0].str.isnumeric().cumsum()

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
Name: Test, dtype: int32
```

Lastly, we can use that series generating the groupings to group by and apply a aggregration of string `join`:

```
df.groupby(df['Test'].str[0].str.isnumeric().cumsum())['Test'].agg(' '.join)

Test
1    123456ab coff-4 eat 8 bagle6
2           345678-edh wine bread
3                567890 tfs grape
Name: Test, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for addressing this promptly.  WOW a one liner.!! impressive. Now I need to break down the code and learn what does what. Can you help with this a bit. what each section does. I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Boomer Sure.  I'll detail out what is going on here.

Comment: Scott, Thanks for taking the time with this and helping me out.  Just impressive!!

Comment: my bad,  I did earlier and it wouldn't let me.  I guess I was too fast approving it. Anyway, all good. Thanks again Take Care

Comment: @Boomer Thank you.  Be safe and stay healthy!